# Defaults write in MacOS never writes or changes the value in defaults

Tags: terminal, macos-catalina

I have been trying to change value for this command and it doesn't work.

This is what it shows:

```
vbabbar@VBabbar-Macbook ~ % defaults read -g com.apple.swipescrolldirection
1

vbabbar@VBabbar-Macbook ~ % defaults write -g com.apple.swipescrolldirection 0
vbabbar@VBabbar-Macbook ~ % defaults read -g com.apple.swipescrolldirection
1 

vbabbar@VBabbar-Macbook ~ % defaults write -g com.apple.swipescrolldirection -bool True
vbabbar@VBabbar-Macbook ~ % defaults read -g com.apple.swipescrolldirection
1

vbabbar@VBabbar-Macbook ~ % defaults write -g com.apple.swipescrolldirection -bool False
vbabbar@VBabbar-Macbook ~ % defaults read -g com.apple.swipescrolldirection
1
```

The read value always shows 1 and never changes to 0. I have tried using 0, `True` and `False` in default write. So is the function for changing defaults in MacOS has been changed since MacOS X - Catalina and above OS 11/12, and 13?

What's a correct method to change defaults via terminal with an example?

```
defaults write .GlobalPreferences_m
```

or

```
defaults read Analytics Option" 
        "HostWindowGeometry/.FullScreen" = 0;
```

or

```
defaults read com.apple.keyboard.fnState" = 0
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

I’ve been trying to figure out the same thing. It looks like you have to kill the process you’re working on with killall so the default doesn’t get automatically overwritten by a running process. I’m not there yet though. [This guy](https://real-world-systems.com/docs/defaults.1.html) has a decent page about it.

Comment: that makes sense. I am having this issue as I try to change `com.apple.AppleMultiTouchTrackpad Clicking`, the changes doesn't seem to be saved. How can I figure out what process I have to kill to prevent it from overwriting my change?